# Rails didn't install correctly, specifically the uninstaller

Tags: terminal, ruby, xcode, rails

I've just installed Rails using railsinstaller.org for OS X, rails and ruby seem to be working OK (checked by running `rails -v`, `ruby --version` and `ruby --help`). But when it installed, I got an error saying that there were errors and the uninstaller didn't install correctly. Something odd I saw was that when I load terminal, I get this showing up

```
Last login: Fri Nov 30 13:12:09 on ttys000 
unknown5c969d7cc475:~ Sam$
```

Specifically the "unknown5c96..." part, I'm not sure if it's related?

I think I might have got the install error as Xcode wasn't installed first, for peace of mind I'd like to uninstall it and load it back on, but when I try and run the installer from the application folder it just asks for my password and then does nothing. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is free tool called JewelleryBox, which is gui for RVM(http://unfiniti.com/software/mac/jewelrybox). With that tool you can install/uninstall ruby/rails, gemsets, and single gems. After this install gcc/xcode command line tools, install new ruby and then install bundler and after install rails and gems that you need